# Which piece of data uniquely identifies an NSManagedObject?

Tags: cocoa, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I have printed out one of my `NSManagedObject`. I guess the `p457` part of the string uniquely identifies it. Am I right?

```
(Variable *) $1 = 0x0a22b870 <Variable: 0xa22b870> (entity: Variable; id: 0xa22b860 <x-coredata://5CC4CBDE-EB20-483E-AAF2-28BCDB584B4C/Variable/p457> ; data: {
    calcArgPrefix = nil;
    calcArgValue = nil;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to track it for debugging then yes, the `x-coredata://5CC4CBDE-EB20-483E-AAF2-28BCDB584B4C/Variable/p457` is a representation of the `NSManagedObjectID` and the bit after the final slash is what will make that instance unique amongst all other instances of the same entity. Be careful though — the value assigned is permitted to be temporary until the object is actually saved to disk, so may change upon `saveContext` if the instance has just been created.

If you need to do something beyond debugging, you should use the `NSManagedObjectID` itself rather than a string or URL representation.

Comment: you can and should check to see if the NSManagedObjectID is a temp id with `– isTemporaryID`